Convert a multi column / row table output into a single string
I have a table called #table1, larger but similar to the one below. I want to move the results to a single string variable.



ColumnA
ColumnB
ColumnC
ColumnD




date1
datavalue1
identifier1
description1


date2
datavalue2
identifier2
description2



I want the table to reference the table as a string variable in a format where columns are separated by an underscore and rows separated by a comma - such as:
@var = 'date1_datavalue1_identifier1_description1,date2_datavalue2_identifier2_description2'

I have done this manually on a smaller scale with the below
select convert(varchar,columnA) + '_' + convert(varchar,ColumnB) + '_' + convert(varchar,columnC) + '_' + convert(varchar,columnD) as comment
from #table1 

Is this possible in SQL and is there a way to do this dynamically that isn't restricted by number of table rows?

string_agg? And you must provide a size when you convert to varchar else you might truncate your values.

There are loads of questions out there on getting a list of all the columns in a table dynamically. Take a peek and see how you get on.

Why do you need to CONVERT the values to start? 'datavalue1' is already a (n)varchar.

I think that's a variation on: "SQL (output) to CSV".

@DaleK , I have seen posts regarding changing a column into a string, but not changing a whole table into a single string. If you have a link you could post that would be helpful.

Why do you "need" to do this in T-SQL? What is the actual end goal? This smells like an XY Problem.

Like all software problems, break it up into smaller parts e.g. (1) Find/build a query to get you a list of all the columns in a table. (2) Find/build a query to return a single string per row (e.g. string_agg) and (3) Find/Build a query to return create a single string per table.

I'm not sure STRING_AGG is the solution here, @DaleK ; that is for delimiting rows, not columns.

It's possible, but let's say you succeed, what's next? Are you gonna frame the variable on your wall or something? It won't be of any use unless you want to transport it somewhere, for that reason, i'd probably go with FOR JSON or FOR XML instead

True, probably maybe concat_ws

None of the columns will ever contain underscores or hyphens? That would make interpreting The String a bit of a challenge.

What's wrong with STRING_AGG(CONCAT_WS('_', column1, column2......), ',')

@HABO not in this case, but if some do for similar problems I can use a double underscore separator or some other character.

What version of sql server you're using?

this is almost always a mistake to do in SQL in the first place. The job is better done in the client code or reporting tool.

You can try below code sample.

dbfiddle Link : https://dbfiddle.uk/W-ZfeIlg

DECLARE @var varchar(max)

SELECT @var = STUFF((SELECT ',' + convert(varchar,columnA) + '_' + convert(varchar,ColumnB) + '_' 
                           + convert(varchar,columnC) + '_' + convert(varchar,columnD)
                    FROM table1 
                    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')

SELECT @var as comment



I think the OP wanted this stuff to be dynamic. Your code doesn't order the table correctly either

Hi Jay, thank you for your response, this is essentially what I need I was just wondering if it could be done dynamically.

For SQL Server 2017
be careful with string limit,null values, implicit conversions
about string agg function
use string_agg and concat function
sample
DECLARE @comments VARCHAR(MAX) = (
SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT_WS('_',ColumnA,ColumnB,ColumnC,ColumnD),',')
  FROM TABLE1)

SELECT @comments as comment

